# Can't load mysql.web assembly

Tags: asp.net, mysql, asp.net-mvc-3

I am making a web application with ASP.net MVC3. I eventually want to use roleprovider and authentication used by a login form. So I have this code:

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="~/Home/Login" timeout="2880" />
</authentication>

<roleManager enabled="true" defaultProvider="MyRoleProvider">
  <providers>
    <add name="MyRoleProvider"
         type="StudentAdministratieProject.Authorisation.CustomRoleProvider"/>
  </providers>
</roleManager>
```

This code is obviously located in my web.config.

The error I get when I start the application:

> Can't load file or assembly MySql.Web, Version=6.7.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d or one of the dependencies can't be loaded. The system cannot find the given file. ** Note that this is roughly translated from Dutch, the error was originally in Dutch.

Any ideas? Ive Googled a lot but can't find anything which helped me!

Comment: Does your project have a reference to MySql.Web? If so, is it in the GAC ? If not, is it set to copy local ?

Comment: I really have no idea.. I did add a reference called mysql.data.dll once. What is the GAC?

Comment: The GAC is the Global Assembly Cache. When an application has a dependency on an external library, the reference is resolved using both the GAC and the current executing folder. If you have installed MySql provider for .NET, it is installed and the DLL are located in a well-known location, but not in the GAC. Your project can reference that DLL but you need to Copy the reference on build. A quick start on the Assembly locating process can be found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa720133.aspx)

Comment: I know this is a beginner mistake, but I got the same error and it took me 10-15 minutes to notice that I simply had not installed MySQL's .NET Connector... I was using VS 2012 Express before (which I don't believe is compatible) so I had never bothered installing it! Once I did, worked like a charm.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

realize this is old, but in case its viewed later, here's what I found is cause / resolution.

I had to do some MySQL work on my regular .NET web server (db and web servers on same machine) so I used the MySQL installer (http://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/mysql-installer-for-windows.html). That little sucker seems to have gone and updated my .NET machine.config for me, how nice, so it's connector will work well with .NET. Stupid installer. Anyways when I went to go use a .NET / SQL Server app (no tie in to MySQL) I got the same error.

Easy enough fix (and your MySQL utilizing apps should still work just fine). Just comment out the MySQL reference(s) in the appropriate .NET framwework machine.config.

NOTE: the web page the error is on will tell you what machine.config file (and line number) is offending.

Link below is more detailed:

http://forums.asp.net/t/1928379.aspx

Comment: indeed little sucker.

Comment: Check the answer provided by Sunny, potentially a better fit per situation than this approach. The comment on that answer by jp2code points out changing the machine.config means you've got a solution tied to the specific installation of visual studio.

Answer (score 14):

My Solution to this question as I do had the same issue:

Just add a reference to MySql.Web and it will go.

Comment: **BINGO!** This is what I needed because I have other apps on this PC that are integrated with *MySql*. If I were to comment out the reference like in *bubson bropa*'s answer, those apps would likely work just fine right up until the next time I rebooted - leaving me scratching my head and wondering why they stopped working.

Comment: my machine.config is not editable? unfortunately i installed connector 6.10.1.0 and then rolled back to 6.9.9 and in machine.config its still showing 6.10.1.0 versions

Comment: @Samra: possible case is it did not remove configuration files. You can try deleting all the files related to Connector versio 6.10.1.0 and re-installing 6.9.9. Hope that works!

Comment: i did an unsinstall of 6.10.1 and it works now...silly it didnt occur to me before

Answer (score 4):

Try reinstalling MySQL .NET Connector 6.9.4 while uncheck “Web Providers” during the installation -

See more at: [ASP.NET with MySQL: Configuration Error (MySql.Web.v20)][1]  http://technowide.net/2014/11/07/asp-net-with-mysql-configuration-error/

Comment: This is the best answer. It's all due to that still-horribly-flawed installation.

Answer (score 2):

I have experienced the same situation and managed to fix the problem with these steps,

1. Read the error information carefully which provides helpful details to rectify the situation.
2. I wouldn't change the machine.config file.
3. As it says Application cannot find a reference to the assembly MySql.Web and the version it is trying to reference is Version=6.7.4.0.
4. Based on path you install MySql you will be able to find the correct assembly files,     ex : C:\Program Files\MySQL\Connector NET 6.7.4\Assemblies\v4.0\MySql.Web.dll
5. Copy C:\Program Files\MySQL\Connector NET 6.7.4\Assemblies\v4.0\MySql.Web.dll file to bin folder. (I would copy all the files in C:\Program Files\MySQL\Connector NET 6.7.4\Assemblies\v4.0\ folder to bin folder)

Hope this helps!
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Another solution:

- check version of .NET used by application pool of your web application. here we consider version is 2.0
- go to folder C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\Connector NET 6.7.4\Assemblies\v2.0 (<- depend of your version)
- copy dll from previous folder to C:\Windows\assembly

Answer (score 0):

I managed to resolve this by running MySQL Installer and updating to the latest files available.

Answer (score 0):

As Beginner to .NET, i also experienced the same situation..

But it can be resolved very simple step.

Select references from solution explorer . Right click on it, Select Add reference, select mysql.web from the list of assemblies, then add it.

After adding mysql.web assembly , you can get rid out from this error.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

I have been looking for answer and I find the solution that work for me on [fix-for-mysql-connectornet-693](http://codeontime.com/blog/2014/09/fix-for-mysql-connectornet-693)

You just need to delete ".v20" from every instance of MySql.Web.v20 in

```
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Config\machine.config
```

and

```
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Config\machine.config
```

You can edit files in Notepad (Run As Administrator!).

Answer (score 0):

For upgrading latest version and solving these kind of issues;

Under Nuget Manager Console run

`PM> Install-Package MySql.Web`

this will download latest MySql.Web for you. From project references find dll version by looking its properties.

Then,change any other version in your web.config with this new version. This works.