# Asp.net Host Configuration Error

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I deployed mvc 4 project and publish to on host than i got some error like this

Could not load file or assembly 'MySql.Web, Version=6.7.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

I didn't use mysql or database connection also i have validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="true" and error page below .net version look like

Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.0.30319.18044

what did i wrong any idea i can't access my provider at the moment.

**Updated. Error Details**

Server Error in '/' Application.

Configuration Error

Description: An error occurred during the processing of a configuration file required to service this request. Please review the specific error details below and modify your configuration file appropriately.

Parser Error Message: Could not load file or assembly 'MySql.Web, Version=6.7.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

Source Error:

[No relevant source lines]

Source File: machine.config    Line: 240

Assembly Load Trace: The following information can be helpful to determine why the assembly 'MySql.Web, Version=6.7.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d' could not be loaded.

WRN: Assembly binding logging is turned OFF.
To enable assembly bind failure logging, set the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog] (DWORD) to 1.
Note: There is some performance penalty associated with assembly bind failure logging.
To turn this feature off, remove the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog].

Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.0.30319.18044

Comment: Do you refer to that assembly in your web.config somewhere?

Comment: I don't have mysql reference in web.config or solution

Comment: If you are not directly refering to that assembly, is any of your references refering to that assembly indirectly?

Comment: i updated the message i am really dont now why this happing

Comment: Looks like someone edited the `machine.config` file?  Well *that's* annoying..

Comment: My provider don't know how to fix that. if i say delete the machine.config Line: 240 is it work ?

Comment: my hosting provider said me "i am not have mvc 4" damn after install mvc 4 worked everything.

Comment: this worked for me: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17436446/cant-load-mysql-web-assembly

Answer (score 0):

As Hudson Bropa mentioned in the comments above, [his answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17436446/cant-load-mysql-web-assembly) did the trick for me.

As in his case, it was a MySql installer modifying the machine config that messed things up, and commenting out the MySqlRoleProvider line got things working again immediately:

```
<!--<add name="MySQLRoleProvider" type="MySql.Web.Security.MySQLRoleProvider, MySql.Web, Version=6.7.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=xxxx" connectionStringName="LocalMySqlServer" applicationName="/" />-->
```

Hope it's of some use, and thanks to Hudson!