# Could not load file or assembly 'MySql.Web, Version=6.7.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d' or one of its dependencies

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2012

I wrote a web site in asp.net with memebership ,I used SQl SERVER for my web site, when I uploaded website to my host , unfortunately it didn't work.

it say :  Could not load file or assembly 'MySql.Web, Version=6.7.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d' or one of its dependencies

but I never used any mysql in entire my project ,

and finally I can't access machine.config in my host ,this happen only when the user wants to login ,other parts of my web site work well and read from database without any problem.

this is my essential part of mywebsite :

```
    <membership defaultProvider="AspNetSqlMembershipProvider">
<providers>
<clear />

<add name="AspNetSqlMembershipProvider" connectionStringName="LocalSqlServer" applicationName="/" minRequiredPasswordLength="6" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="true" passwordFormat="Hashed" type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider" />
</providers>
</membership>
<!--Profile-->
<profile>
<properties>
<clear />
<add name="level" />
<add name="lastword" />
<add name="section" />
</properties>

</profile>
```

[Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0jugC.jpg)

sorry, I'm not professional , please answer me completely.

thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can't load mysql.web assembly](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17436446/cant-load-mysql-web-assembly)

If you look at that it explains what causes this. Basicly you have a reference to MySQL dll that you need to remove. Google Adding/Removing references for info on that

Answer (score 1):

On your dev box (that works)....do a search in this folder

c:\windows\Microsoft.NET\

for "machine.config"

Based on which version your IIS is running (usually 2.0 or 4.0)......find the machine.config file.

Open it up and look for

```
MySql.Web
```

That will explain why it works on a dev box and not on your deployment site.

You have to rectify this.

See:

[Can't load mysql.web assembly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17436446/cant-load-mysql-web-assembly)

(The accepted answer)

Comment: I landed here through Google and this answer pointed me in the right direction.